# Linear gradient background with grid in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gradient, linear-gradients

I want to achieve this background

[image]

This are the CSS code available on figma.

whole backgraound :
Linear Gradient
rgba(22, 25, 24, 1)
rgba(22, 25, 24, 0.9417)
rgba(22, 25, 24, 0.8344)
rgba(22, 25, 24, 0.7341)
rgba(22, 25, 24, 0.4)

particular one box's color :

rgba(217, 217, 217, 1)

Here is the code that I have tried :

```
 Container(
              height: 191.h,
              width: Get.size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: tempInfo(),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  65.w,
                  65.h,
                  65.w,
                  83.84.h,
                ),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 42.16.h,
                  width: 260.w,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: AppColors.color3C.withOpacity(1),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          20.r,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "View Similar Templates",
                      style: tempInfoButton(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

LinearGradient tempInfo() => LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        // Color.fromRGBO(22, 25, 24, 1),
        // Color.fromRGBO(22, 25, 24, 0.9417),
        // Color.fromRGBO(22, 25, 24, 0.8344),
        // Color.fromRGBO(22, 25, 24, 0.7341),
        // Color.fromRGBO(22, 25, 24, 0.4),
        AppColors.color18.withOpacity(1),
        AppColors.color18.withOpacity(0.9417),
        AppColors.color18.withOpacity(0.83444),
        AppColors.color18.withOpacity(0.7341),
        AppColors.color18.withOpacity(0.4),
      ],
      begin: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
      end: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
    );
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you;ve tried so far? [LinearGradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with this snippet. I will recommend checking [flutter/painting/BoxDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html)

```dart
SizedBox(
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          //background image
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Image.network(
              'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),

          const Positioned.fill(
            child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.black54],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                backgroundColor: Colors.green, //box color
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text("Button"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )),
```

Comment: It's no use background is not even visible, it's the same code I have written. Please provide more efficient code & explanation.

Comment: I may use ImageFilter for this or `image` from DecorationBox

Comment: Try with Stack for startUp